# Why is there an ambiguous call for templatized function?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with creating a template in c++. I am using xcode for mac.

When passing an `int` to a `swap` function I get the error code "ambiguous call". However, passing `string`s works fine. Why is that?

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>

void swap(T& c, T& d)
{
    T temp = c;
    c = d;
    d = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;

    swap(a, b);                   // this is an error "ambiguous call"
    cout << a << "\t" << b;

    string first_name = "Bob";
    string last_name = "Hoskins";
    swap(first_name, last_name);  // this works

    cout << first_name << "\t" << last_name;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never do `using namespace std;`. Your function conflicts with std::swap. If you had read the error message and posted it here, you would notice std::swap there.

Comment: your `swap` is conflicting with [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) for the reason @S.M. mentioned.

Comment: Either remove `using namespace std;` (read more about [why `using namespace std;` is considered bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) or put your `swap` in another namespace and call `your_ns::swap`

Comment: I think the fact that the call to `swap` *does* work when called with strings, but not with ints, is interesting, and is certainly reproducible.

Comment: @AlanBirtles The target is not really appropriate. While it's good advice, it doesn't cover why the call with string arguments works. I would agree with the target if the OP only had calls to swap that didn't work. I'm reopening the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `using namespace std;` which brings `std::swap` into scope. This means the template `swap` that you have written conflicts with `std::swap`, and you get an ambiguous call when you pass it 2 ints.

Takeaway: **Never** do `using namespace std;`

The interesting part is that calling `swap` with 2 `std::string`s works. That's because there is a [specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/swap2) of `std::swap` for `std::string`. The specialization is considered a better match, and so it's called instead of your own `swap`.

Comment: "Never" is harsh. Make it "Know what you are doing if you".

Comment: @j6t I don't want the phrasing to be harsh, but at the same time, I don't want to soft pedal it. It's a very problematic thing to do, and I haven't really come across cases where it's appropriate *even if* the programmer who wrote it knows exactly what they're doing.